# ERRor report,Float object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

```
def vol_sphere(rad):
    radf=float(rad)
    return (int(str(4.0/3)*(3.14)(radf**3)))
OUTPUT


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-23740cf5751c> in <module>
----> 1 vol_sphere(2.3)

<ipython-input-17-e9beec0fa42c> in vol_sphere(rad)
      1 def vol_sphere(rad):
      2     radf=float(rad)
----> 3     return (int(str(4.0/3)*(3.14)(radf**3)))

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: Did you mean to have a `*` between `(3.14)(radf**3)`?

Comment: tips: dont use unnamed values, always try to keep them under some meaningful varaiables. + in `math` module You got `pi`, just use it

Comment: in `(int(str(4.0/3)*(3.14)(radf**3)))` you multiply a string with a float - did you mean `str(round(4/3*3.14*radf**3))` ?